# Analysis Exam Questions

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, circles

I am going to have an analysis exam soon and I found the following question in a past paper:

Evaluate

$$\int \frac{-y \, dx + x \, dy}{x^2+y^2}$$

a) Once counterclockwise around the circle $$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

b) Once counterclockwise around the circle $$(x-2)^2 + y^2 = 1$$

Could someone please tell me how to solve this? I can't seem to get my head around as to how I should start.

Comment: It looks like the imaginary part of $$\int\frac {dz}{z} \ . $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterize the contour.

a) $x=\cos{t}$, $y=\sin{t}$, $dx=-\sin{t} \, dt$, $dy=\cos{t} \, dt$, $t \in [0,2\pi)$

$$\oint_{\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}} \frac{-y \, dx + x \, dy}{x^2+y^2} = \int_0^{2 \pi} dt \frac{\cos^2{t}+\sin^2{t}}{\cos^2{t}+\sin^2{t}} = 2 \pi$$

Can you do b)?  (This time, $x=2 + \cos{t}$,...)

Comment: So then for b) it would be 2pi as well, correct?

Comment: According to my comment it should be $0$ by Cauchy's Theorem.